# File not found after compile to js

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, electron

im trying to set up an electron app with typescript.

So in my app.ts i have to following statement to tell electron which file should be opened:

```
win.loadURL(`file://../views/index.html`);
```

When i had only javascript it worked fine.
But now after compiling electron just opens an empty window.

Because im compiling my typescript to a different directory.

Is there a variable for the root dir or something dynamic path resolution i could use?

Thanks

Comment: How are you "compiling" your typescript? Is this with `webpack` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused because your file location is not absolute, this may be fine when debugging your app because your running it from a specific place but once you compile it will not be able to find the file try using something like this:

`win.loadURL(__dirname + "../views/index.html");`

[__dirname](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname) is a variable provided by NodeJS which is the absolute location to the directory of the current file.